# Pass parameter from URL to controller function with correct type in CakePHP

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, types, php-7

I am developing a RESTful API using PHP 7 and CakePHP 4.0.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Api;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class ProductsController extends AppController
{
    public function list(int $categoryId, int $limit = 10, int $page = 1)
    {
        // here's my code with queries and so on
    }

}
```

I would like to call my endpoint with a GET request to this URL:

```
http://example.com/api/products/list/33/30/1
```

But I get this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\Api\ProductsController::list() must be of the type integer, string given, called in /var/www/repo/public/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php on line 521
```

Now, a very simple solution would be to just remove the type from the parameters in the signature of the `list` method, like this (because, if I just remove the type from the `$categoryId` parameter, then I get the same error for the other ones):

```
public function list($categoryId, $limit = 10, $page = 1)
```

But I'd much rather prefer to keep the "correct" types in my method signature.
Am I out of luck here, or is there a way (maybe in the routing configuration, or somewhere else) to prevent Cake (or PHP itself?) to cast the parameters in the URL to string?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or run `bin/cake version`). Simple request parameter type coercion is supported as of CakePHP 4.3.

Comment: @ndm I'm using CakePHP 4.0. I edited the question.

Comment: If you indeed are using a `4.0.x` release, then the answer is that it's not going to work (unless you implement your own controller factory that does the type coercion), and you'd need to upgrade to `4.3.x`.

Comment: @ndm could you please provide a link to somewhere in the 4.3 documentation that shows this new type coercion feature? I'm having a hard time finding anything about it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's specific notes regarding that feature, other than in the migration guide: **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-3-migration-guide.html#id8**. Might be worth adding to the routing/controller docs.

Answer (score -1):

localhost/cakephp210?id=123          //this is my url

public function profile($id){

```
//this is my profile method in controller here i want to get  my id here

 using method $id parameter    help me any one
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).